# タグのマージ: [web-scraping] と [スクレイピング]

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案, タグの付け替えの提案

web-scrapingタグとスクレイピングタグが両方存在し、目視で同一主題であると確認しました。
「スクレイピング」タグを「web-scraping」にマージ&タグシノミムとしたいです。

Comment: これ私も昔同じことを思った記憶があります。たしか本家 Stack Overflow だと [web-scraping] の他に、質問数は相対的に僅かながら [screen-scraping]、[pdf-scraping]、[console-scraping]、[ram-scraping]、そして [robotic-scraping] があって、更に [scraping] は [screen-scraping] のシノニムとなっていたので迷ってやめたのだったと思います。web-scraping 以外の「スクレイピング」が日本で使われているかどうかを判断基準にすると良さそうです。私はウェブスクレイピング以外の言葉は辞書でしか見たことないのですが、実際使われている言葉なのでしょうかね……？

Comment: For us to merge tags we need consenus from the community. Since there doesn't seem to be a significant support for this to be done. I am moving this to status-declined. Given that its 4 years old, feel free to bring it up again.

Comment: @nekketsuuu この件、nekketsuuu さんが「調査中」タグを付与した時点では必ずしもStack Exchange社にエスカレーションする意図は無かったものが、
「調査中」タグの意味が[2020年に変わった](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/348970)ことにより偶発的にエスカレーションしてしまったものと思いますが、この理解で間違いないでしょうか。

Comment: @mjy はいそうです。

Answer (score 3):

[スクレイピング](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%83%ac%e3%82%a4%e3%83%94%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0) より [web-scraping](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) の方が指している範囲が狭いので、タグをマージしてしまうと将来的に問題が出るかもしれません（マージすると、子になった方のタグをつけることができなくなるからです）。

代わりに [スクレイピング](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%83%ac%e3%82%a4%e3%83%94%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0) タグを [web-scraping](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) へ付け替え (retag)、[スクレイピング](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%83%ac%e3%82%a4%e3%83%94%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0) のタグ wiki に [web-scraping](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) への誘導を書いておくのはいかがでしょうか。

参考: [What's the difference between [retag-request] and [synonym-request]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298742/341401)

Comment: 「マージすると、子になった方のタグをつけることができなくなる」の「マージ」は「別名の設定」の間違いでしょうか。

Comment: ああ、これは間違っていますね。別名を書きたかったのだと思います。

Answer (score 3):

（追記: 下記の通りに行ないました）

この件には、やや混乱が有りますので、モデレーターとして私が行なう予定の内容を説明いたします。ご意見が有ればお寄せ下さい。

#### 「却下」タグをはずします

現在このメタ質問は、Stack Exchange社により「却下」となっています。しかし、通常はタグのマージや別名の設定はユーザーによる議論で決定しており、実行もモデレーター権限で可能です。つまり、本来はStack Exchange社に判断を委ねる理由が無かったものです。

よって、ユーザーによる議論や作業を継続するのが適当であると考え、「却下」タグは一旦削除いたします。

なお、この件がStack Exchange社にエスカレーションされてしまったのは、「[調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad)」タグの意味が[2020年に変わった](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/348970)ことによるアクシデントです。今後は起らないはずです。

#### タグの扱い

支持されている nekketsuuu さんの回答に基づいて、以下のことを行ないます。

- 別名:
  現在出されている別名候補、「スクレイピング → web-scraping」は一旦削除します。
- 付け替え（マージ）:
  「スクレイピングタグをweb-scrapingへ付け替え」は既にどなたかが実行済みのようです。
  よって、そのままにします。
- 「スクレイピング」タグのWiki:
  上の結果として、現在は「スクレイピング」タグが付いた質問が有りませんので、タグWikiも作れません。
  今後、「スクレイピング」タグが発生するようならば、「スクレイピング のタグ wiki に web-scraping への誘導を書いておく」という作業を行なうこととします。